# Add new Item into itemsource or into Datagrid on reaching last row index

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm developing spreadsheet type POINT OF SALE (POS), in which items will be entered same like in excel and navigate from cell to cell by down, left, right arrows keys.
When programs runs, i've entered 10 empty items into datagrid same like as excel empty sheet, thats why when user entered some value in first cell, the item information gets from database and update Datagrid. At this point, programs works fine for 10 items.

```
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Code, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Quantity, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <EventSetter Event="TextChanged" Handler="CellValueChanged" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Unit Price" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding UnitPrice, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sub-Total" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding SubTotal, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Event:

```
private void Datagrid_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridCellInfo cell = Datagrid.SelectedCells[0];

            var generator = Datagrid.ItemContainerGenerator;
            int columnIndex = cell.Column.DisplayIndex;
            int rowIndex = generator.IndexFromContainer(generator.ContainerFromItem(cell.Item));


            if (header == "Code")
            {
                if (Datagrid.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
                {


                    //int counts = Datagrid.Items.Count;
                    //MessageBox.Show(counts.ToString() +" index "+rowIndex);
                    //MessageBox.Show("total counts: " + counts.ToString() + "Selected index " + rowIndex.ToString() + " column index: " + columnIndex);

                    var grid = sender as DataGrid;
                    var selected = grid.SelectedItems;
                    foreach (var items in selected)
                    {
                        if (items as Item != null)
                        {
                            string code = ((Item)Datagrid.Items[rowIndex]).Code;
                            Database database = new Database();
                            database.DBOpen();

                            SQLiteDataReader sQLiteDataReader = database.GetWhere(Database.TABLE_ITEMS, Database.CODE_ITEMS, code);
                            while (sQLiteDataReader.Read())
                            {
                                string name = sQLiteDataReader.GetString(2);
                                string desc = sQLiteDataReader.GetString(6);
                                string unitPrice = sQLiteDataReader.GetInt64(8).ToString();
                                string quantity = "1";
                                //string subTotal = (double.Parse(quantity) * double.Parse(unitPrice)).ToString();
                                //grossAmount = grossAmount + Double.Parse(subTotal);

                                Item item = new Item()
                                {
                                    Code = code,
                                    Name = name,
                                    Description = desc,
                                    Quantity = quantity,
                                    UnitPrice = unitPrice,
                                    //SubTotal = subTotal
                                };
                                ((Item)Datagrid.Items[rowIndex]).Code = code;
                                ((Item)Datagrid.Items[rowIndex]).Name = name;
                                ((Item)Datagrid.Items[rowIndex]).Description = desc;
                                ((Item)Datagrid.Items[rowIndex]).Quantity = quantity;
                                ((Item)Datagrid.Items[rowIndex]).UnitPrice = unitPrice;
                            }
                            database.DBClose();
                        }
                    }
                    }
```

As you can see in Event code (currentcellchanged), i'm getting selected cell value and their relevent information from database and update by using `((Item)Datagrid.Items[rowIndex]).Code = code;` etc.

The problem is how user able to enter 11th, 12th entry?

Note: i've write some code in Event section,

```
 if (rowIndex > 10)
        {
            var list = (IList<Item>)Datagrid.ItemsSource;

            list.Add(new Item());
        }
```

but got exception.

> ```
> Exception: Information for developers (use Text Visualizer to read this):
> This exception was thrown because the generator for control 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid Items.Count:13' with name 'Datagrid'
> ```
>
> has received sequence of CollectionChanged events that do not agree
>   with the current state of the Items collection.  The following
>   differences were detected:
>         Accumulated count 12 is different from actual count 13.  [Accumulated count is (Count at last Reset + #Adds - #Removes since
>   last Reset).]
>         At index 10:  Generator's item 'Inventory_Control.Classes.Item' is different from actual item 'Inventory_Control.Classes.Item'.
>         At index 11:  Generator's item '{NewItemPlaceholder}' is different from actual item 'Inventory_Control.Classes.Item'.
>
> ```
> One or more of the following sources may have raised the wrong events:
>      System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator
>       System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection
>        System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView
>         System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Inventory_Control.Classes.Item,
> ```
>
> Inventory Control, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]
>       (The starred sources are considered more likely to be the cause of the problem.)
>
> ```
> The most common causes are (a) changing the collection or its Count without raising a corresponding event, and (b) raising an event
> ```
>
> with an incorrect index or item parameter.
>
> ```
> The exception's stack trace describes how the inconsistencies were detected, not how they occurred.  To get a more timely exception, set
> ```
>
> the attached property 'PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel' on the
>   generator to value 'High' and rerun the scenario.  One way to do this
>   is to run a command similar to the following:
>          System.Diagnostics.PresentationTraceSources.SetTraceLevel(myItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator,
>   System.Diagnostics.PresentationTraceLevel.High)
>       from the Immediate window.  This causes the detection logic to run after every CollectionChanged event, so it will slow down the
>   application.

```
 void AddValues()
        {
            Datagrid.ItemsSource = null;

            List<Item> list = new List<Item>();
            list.Clear();

            for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
            {
                string number = i.ToString();
                Item item = new Item()
                {
                };
                list.Add(item);
            }


            Datagrid.ItemsSource = list;
        }
```

Comment: `The problem is how user able to enter 11th, 12th entry?` I'm pretty sure you didn't debug it... just step through it and see how

Comment: please read exception